# I am able to get the div to only display one at a time, but now I can't get the div to turn off

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to turn off all of the class annotation div and then turn on one specific ID after the fact. I am doing this to try and ensure that only one annotation can be open at a time. However, with the following Javascript, I have gotten it so that only one annotation can be open at a given time, but now it's impossible to close the annotation by clicking it! Any ideas about how I might solve this?

Here is the text where the links to the annotations would be found

```
<div class="text">Here is some text. 
In this text there are links <a href="#" class=annoa onclick="myAnnotation(1)">here</a> 
and there are links <a href="#" class=annoa onclick="myAnnotation(2)">there</a>. 
And there are probably many more! 
They each open their own annotation on the side.</div>
```

Here are the annotations themselves

```
<div class="annotation" id="an1">I'm the first annotation!</div>
<div class="annotation" id="an2">And I'm another one!</div>
```

And here is the Javascript that is giving me trouble

```
function myAnnotation(argument) {

var x = document.getElementById("an" + argument);

  document.getElementById(y).style.display = "none";

  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }

  y = "an" + argument;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are a few things wrong with your code:

1. `id`'s must be **unique**, you have `an1` defined twice
2. You never actually pass anything to the function `myAnnotation` despite it expecting `argument`
3. Onclick of `<a>` the link will attempt to post & will not have the expected functionality

See my example on how to get you started, you can modify this to be more dynamic but at least you'll be on the right track.

```css
.annotation, .annotation a {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  Here is some text.
  In this text there are links
  <a href="#" class="link" onclick="myAnnotation('an1')">here</a>
  and there are links
  <a href="#" class="link" onclick="myAnnotation('an2')">there</a>.
  And there are probably many more!
  They each open their own annotation on the side.</div>

<div class="annotation" id="an1">I'm the first annotation!</div>
<div class="annotation" id="an2">And I'm another one!</div>

<script>
function myAnnotation(id) {
   var element = document.getElementById(id);
   if(element.style.display == 'block')
      element.style.display = 'none';
   else
      element.style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response! I made a mistake in copying in my text! Sorry! I've updated it now. The links use something like this (no repeating IDs) <a href="#" class=annoa onclick="myAnnotation(whateverargumentnumber)"></a>

Comment: That's okay, have a go at implementing my solution and see how you get on

Comment: When I run the code snippet, I seem to have the same problem as the one I am describing in my question :( I want a second click on the link to close the annotation

Comment: Please see my updated code & **please note** call the function like this: `onclick="myAnnotation('an1')"` instead of `myAnnotation(2)`

Comment: If this particular part is solved, just resolve it & create a new question & I'll try to help resolving that too!